# What are Controllers & Components in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What are Controllers & Components in EmberJS

Comment: your question can be elaborated more ?.

Comment: they are explained in the [dok-yuh-men-tey-shuh](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/) - *manuals, listings, diagrams, and other hard- or soft-copy written and graphic materials that describe the use, operation, maintenance, or design of software or hardware*

Answer (score 0):

A component in Ember.JS is just like a feature or plugin. It incorporates into your whole system. They also have a front-end output template where data that was manipulated in the javascript gets outputted / used.

Controllers are very similar but more specialised, but work similarly as a plugin that gets routed (called on a certain request.)

Read this

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/tutorial/simple-component/